# JSON_exporter prometheus does not show string only numbers

Tags: json, prometheus, monitoring, endpoint, exporter

I am busy with a monitoring dashboard. A few of my applications have health endpoints with the following structure: {"status":"UP"}

I am using json_exporter for prometheus to scrape the JSON from the endpoint. When I am trying to scrape the endpoint I get a blank page back from json_exporter. When I tested a number like this: {"status":1} it works and I get info back. I cannot change the structure of the status so I have to scrape a String. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The settings are shown below:
[JSON exporter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny0lW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this!

I think you're going to want:

```
metrics
- name: status
  help: your help description here
  path: '{.status == "UP"}'
  values:
  - up: 1
```

Prometheus metrics are numerical. This should (IIUC) convert a JSON field `status` with value `UP` into a Prometheus counter metric called `up` with a value of `1`.

You're going to want some way to differentiate between different health points (using Prometheus labels). It's unclear from your example, how you'd do this.

Comment: I like the idea a lot so thank you for that. But your settings still do not work. I have played around a bit with this idea but no luck.

Comment: I tried it this morning. Unfortunately, I think it may not be possible assuming that your healthcheck returns `{"status":"UP"}`. This is because, you want to set the metric's value based upon the JSON property value e.g. `UP` and the only way (I think) you can do this with JSONPath is to use a filter which requires a slice. If your healthchecks were returning a slice of `status` i.e. `[{"status":"UP"}]`, then you could use `"{[?(@.status==\"UP\")]}"`

Comment: Thank you for checking @DazWilkin . There is not much documentation on this so it is very nice to be able to speak to people on stackoverflow. I have decided to try http status monitoring.